# Can I apply a specific style to the first item of an ObservableCollection in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, observablecollection

I’m wondering whether there’s a way to apply a specific style to the first element of an `ObservableCollection` in Xamarin. I’d like to customize it so that it renders in a specific way than the others. I’ve made a lot of research so far, but I wasn’t able to find anything that could help me. Is it really possible to do such a thing? My question doesn’t provide code because I’ve still to start the project I have in mind.

Comment: an ObservableCollection is a data object, it does not have any UI to style.  What kind of UI object are you using to render it?

Comment: I thought about using a `CollectionView` and specifying the `CollectionView.ItemTemplate`.

Comment: you could use a DataTemplateSelector but you would have to have some property on your item to distinguish the first from the others

Answer (score 3):

As Jason's reply, you can use [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector) to do this, you need one property to distinguish the first item from the others.

I do one sample that you can take a look:

Creating a DataTemplateSelector:

```
public class itemDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate firsttemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate secondtemplate { get; set; }
    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        if(((itemdata)item).isfirst==true)
        {
            return firsttemplate;
        }
        return secondtemplate;
       
    }
}
```

Consuming a DataTemplateSelector in XAML

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="firstitemTemplate">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label
                FontSize="Large"
                Text="{Binding name}"
                TextColor="Green" />
            <Label
                FontSize="Large"
                Text="{Binding age}"
                TextColor="Green" />
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="seconditemTemplate">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="{Binding name}" TextColor="Red" />
            <Label Text="{Binding age}" TextColor="Red" />
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
    <selector:itemDataTemplateSelector
        x:Key="itemdatatemplateselector"
        firsttemplate="{StaticResource firstitemTemplate}"
        secondtemplate="{StaticResource seconditemTemplate}" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Applying for Collectionview

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemdatatemplateselector}" ItemsSource="{Binding items}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I use isfirst Boolen property to distinguish the first item from the others.

```
 public partial class Page14 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<itemdata> items { get; set; }
    public Page14()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        items = new ObservableCollection<itemdata>()
        {
            new itemdata(){name="cherry",age=28,isfirst=true },
            new itemdata(){name="cherry 1",age=28,isfirst=false },
            new itemdata(){name="cherry 2",age=28,isfirst=false },
            new itemdata(){name="cherry 3",age=28,isfirst=false },
            new itemdata(){name="cherry 4",age=28,isfirst=false }
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}

public class itemdata
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public Boolean isfirst { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete example. Unfortunately, I receive the objects used as `ItemSource` from the outside, from a Web API, and they don’t own a property that distinguishes the first from the second, the third, and so on. So, I’d need to loop on them and add the `isfirst` property to each of them.